# Why is a SoapActionCallBack sometimes necessairy?

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-ws, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm working on a webservice client using Spring-WS. It's not my first webservice project, using Spring-WS. But I am new in this particular project.

We generate dao-objects by using the maven-jaxb2-plugin.

I'm using Spring-WS WebServiceTemplate, with a standard marshaller and unmarshaller set.

In a previous project, I could just do my webservice calls using:

```
webserviceTemplate.marshallSendAndReceive(new ObjectFactory().createSomeRequest());
```

In my current project, I need to provide a SoapActionCallback, provided with the SoapActionUrl.

```
webserviceTemplate.marshallSendAndReceive(new ObjectFactory().createSomeRequest, new SoapActionCallback("http://some-action-url.com/action"));
```

If I do not provide this SoapActionUrl, I don't get a result, and when debugging, I see a surpressed exception:

```
Couldn't get a SAX parser while constructing a envelope
```

I'd like to remove those SoapActionUrls. Using the correct generated objects by maven-jaxb2-plugin, should automatically refer to the correct actionurl?

I've googled this, but did not find too much info about it.
I'd like to know why I just could 'leave the SoapActionCallback' in the first case, and in the second case, I'm obligated to provide this. 
I'm not aware of specific technology used on the server-side, as the webservices are developed by an external partner.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: No it shouldn't automatically refer to the correct action URL. If that is needed or not depends on the contract, the WSDL. If that has specified a SOAP Action for a specific service you need to specify it and there is no XSD or JAXB generated object that can help you with that.

Comment: Not clear why that parameter is required. In the official example (https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/), the parameter pointed to non-existing page and the app still works.